# Flutter how to click a button on webpage?

Tags: html, http, flutter, dart

I'm using flutter `html` package to get document's from webpage, and I'm now wondering if I can click on button on this webpage or event enter text in input to sign in before get data from that webpage

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same. Have you found a solution?

In my case there is a disclaimer page that shows up in front of the content. I have to somehow programatically press the OK-button to get forwarded to the actual page.